# Unclear multiplication with Riemann zeta functional equation with eta

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

In the region 0 < Re(s) < 1 we know that

$$
\zeta(s) = 1/(1-2^{1-s}) \sum_1^\infty (-1)^{n+1}/n^s\,.
$$

This is a multiplication of two complex numbers.

Question 1: Am I right to suppose that in case of zeros of $$\zeta(s), 0 < Re(s) < 1 $$ either the summation term, or the term before the summation has to be zero?

Question 2:  If that is true, then am I right to suppose that it is the summation term that will always be zero?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes and yes. Observe though that $\;1-2^{1-s}\;$ vanishes at many certain points...yet the zeta function is still analytic there. How come?

Comment: thanks, and also for the thoughts...